# GoogleAdsSampleActivity not working?

Tags: android, admob

I am new to admob and I am trying to get the Sample ads to work for the sample activity but when I build it it just comes up with a blank screen?  Yes I have added my admob id to the string and added the google-play-services_lib to the library property and log cat is giving me these errors

```
2-25 16:48:37.218: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25818): The Google Play services resources     
were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are      
included.
02-25 16:48:37.218: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25818): The Google Play services resources     
were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are   
included.
02-25 16:49:06.683: E/SQLiteLog(25818): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of  
[00bb9c9ce4]
02-25 16:49:06.683: E/SQLiteLog(25818): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/FileSyetmQuota.db) 
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818): ERROR: 
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818): SQLite database failed to load from    
/FileSyetmQuota.db
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818): Cause - unable to open database file
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818):   
external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool  
WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
02-25 16:49:06.683: E/SQLiteLog(25818): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of 
[00bb9c9ce4]
02-25 16:49:06.683: E/SQLiteLog(25818): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2)    
open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - 
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818): ERROR: 
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818): SQLite database failed to load from   
/NotificationPermissions.db
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818): Cause - unable to open database file
02-25 16:49:06.683: D/WebKit(25818):        
external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool   
WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
02-25 16:49:06.683: I/Ads(25818): Ad request cancelled.
02-25 16:49:06.688: E/webview(25818): removeForStylusPenEvent onDetachedFromWindow
02-25 16:49:06.688: E/webview(25818): removeForStylusPenEvent START
02-25 16:49:06.688: E/webview(25818): removeForStylusPenEvent END
```

Heres the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<!-- Used to request banner and interstitial ads. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Used to avoid sending an ad request if there is no connectivity. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BannerXmlActivity"
        android:label="@string/banner_in_xml"/>
    <activity android:name=".BannerCodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/banner_in_code"/>
    <activity android:name=".InterstitialActivity"
        android:label="@string/interstitial"/>
    <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smal lestScreenSize"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What does your Manifest look like and also your XML for the activity?

Comment: You should post your relevant code regarding to the creation of that AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

First put **Google Mobile Ads SDK** into lib folder

After activating your account on [Admob](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/), you need to config one application in your acccount. After that application Admob will provide you the Android SDK for Admob containing admob.jar and working example.

```
private void AdmobFooterInitialize(){
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "Your_AdMobPUBLISHERID");
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.addTestDevice("your device id"); // this for testing 
    request.setTesting(false);
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

in your manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

How to get deviceId:-

```
     final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
```